# self keyword semantics when changing an instance method to class method

Tags: ios

```
-(UIView*)showMenu{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400)];
    [view addSubview:self.menuTableView];
    return view;
}
```

I have this really simple function, which works fine. But then I wanted to make the function a class method (so I wouldn't have to make an instance of the class to use it..), and thus prefixed it with + instead.

Which results in error message: Member reference type 'struct obj_class' is a pointer, maybe u meant to use ->. I try that, but still error. Can somebody pls explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` variable inside an instance method refers to the instance of the object on which the instance method is called.

Since class methods are not associated with any particular instance, `self` means the `Class` object on which the class method is defined. Since `Class` class does not have a member called `menuTableView`, the compiler reports an error.

Comment: just for clearness how would i go about adding a class member?

Comment: @DevilInDisguise You can add class methods, but you cannot add data members to it, because `Class` is a `typedef` of a special `struct` defined by Objective-C runtime library.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand that, since a struct normally contains data members

Comment: @DevilInDisguise `Class` is a `typedef`-ed pointer to is a predefined `struct` called `objc_class`. Since it is defined inside the runtime library, i.e. outside of your code, you cannot add members to it. The definition of `Class` is as follows: `typedef struct objc_class *Class;` You can find more info [here](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html).